# Make Internet Explorer 7 always get the latest version of a page?

Tags: internet-explorer, cache

I'm developing a web site.  Internet Explorer 7 keeps displaying cached copies of previous versions of my pages.  How do I make Internet 7 Explorer get the page from the server with each page load instead of using cached copies?

In previous versions, this setting was easy to find, but I'm having trouble figuring this out in Internet Explorer 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... it always seems to work fine for me if I go to the **Tools** Menu, **Internet Options**, **Settings** button, and set the option for "**Check for newer versions of stored pages:**" to "**Every time I visit the webpage**"  Have you tried this?  Doesn't it work for you?  It's been in the same place, as far as I know since at least IE6.

Comment: Although this setting will solve issues for you as you develop your site, **BE SURE** to set your HTTP Headers correctly on your final production web server... as most users **should** have the "Automatic" setting selected in IE to allow proper caching as web servers direct.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you're looking for, but one way to do this is add these tags to the head during development.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

This has the added benefit of working across all browsers (in theory). There is also a keyboard shortcut to force a reload in Internet Explorer: Ctrl+Shift+F5.

Comment: Definitely not the answer I was looking for :-/  Why isn't the setting easy to find?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I'm not sure if it's part of IE7, but they (Microsoft) did release a development bar for IE - this enables you to force a reload of cache each page.

[Development bar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535)

(From the overview page):
*Selectively clear the browser cache and saved cookies. Choose from all objects or those associated with a given domain.*

I was running ASP.NET at the time, so another way is to pass and change the querystring each time, e.g `mypage.aspx?querystring=1, mypage.aspx?querystring=2, mypage.aspx?querystring=3`.

Hopefully the development bar will help you though.

Edit: Also, `Ctrl + F5` is *supposed* to clear the page cache too, but obviously that's a manual process.

Answer (score 0):

To access the "Check for newer versions of stored pages" option in IE7, 8 and 9:

Tools -> Internet Options -> General Tab -> Click "Settings" button under the Browsing History section.